# 8051 micro controller on chip ROM address range? MEMORY SIZE

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, memory, 8051

[image]

what is the size for each of these chip ?
I know that when we add 1 bit to the memory we double the size.
my question is what is the size for a chip range from (0FFF - 0000) so that i keep doubling when ever I add a bit !

Answer (score 1):

Those values are obviously in hex: `0FFF = 4095`, `1FFF = 8192` and `7FFF = 32767`. Since there is a byte at address zero, you have full 4KB, 8KB and 32KB of ROM on the corresponding chip.